# Is there a Kronecker symbol in Maple?

Tags: maple

The kronecker-symbol for two integers `n,m` is defined as `1` if `n=m` and `0` otherwise.

Is there an inbuilt kronecker-symbol in maple or an easy way to implement it?

Sorry, if I should have overlooked something trivial, the maple-homepage is down at the moment and google did not return anything helpful.

**Edit:** I Just found something useful [here](http://www.digi-area.com/Maple/atlas/help/delta.php):

```
restart:
delta := table(symmetric,identity);
simplify(delta[1,2]);
simplify(delta[1,1]);

        delta := TABLE(symmetric, identity, [])
                           0
                           1
```

However it does not seem to simplify even trivial expressions with symbols:

```
simplify(delta[n,n]);
simplify(delta[n,n+1]);

                      delta[n, n]
                    delta[n, n + 1]
```

where one would expect to obtain `1` and `0`, respectively.

**Edit 2:** I also tried it this way:

```
restart:
delta := proc(n,m):
    if n=m then 1 else 0 fi;
end;
delta(1,2);
delta(1,1);
delta(n,n);

0
1
1
```

However, this also works poorly for symbols, as

```
delta(n,m);
```

returns `0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this
**delta:= (m,n)->
     `if`(evalb(m < n)::truefalse, `if`(m=n,1,0), 'procname'(m,n))
;**

Comment: The if's in my answer need to be in backquotes. This editor stripped my backquotes \`.  Okay, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a built-in function called [KroneckerDelta](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=Physics/KroneckerDelta) in the [Physics](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=Physics) package. Try this

```
with(Physics):
KroneckerDelta[i,j];
```

where i and j take integer values. This gives 1 when i=j and 0 when i =/= j.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer something like this: `delta:=(mu,nu)->eval(evalb(mu=nu),[true=1,false=0])`